Where can I store the secret key that I use to encrypt the body of my requests?
I have a KMM Library project and I am writing an SDK that will be sold. I need to encrypt the body of the requests sent to the back-end. Where can I store the encryption key? The person who receives the SDK should not have access to this key.
I'm not sure how appropriate it is to store it in local.properties or another file, because this SDK will be handed over to the purchasers. Therefore, I cannot embed it in the code as a constant either. As far as I know, reverse engineering can be done on the keystore. What is the most appropriate method?

You can use asymmetric encryption. Distribute the SDK with a public key. Data encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the corresponding private key, which you keep secret and do not distribute.

First of all: This seems to be an XY Problem. Why would you even need to encrypt the body? And if you really need this, I'd refrain from using the same key for all of your users but implement some well known key exchange scheme (like for instance Diffie-Hellman). With such a scheme you can negotiate an encryption key without the need of storing it at hte client side.
